# gitolite: 'on-demand' creation of wild repositories

Tags: git, gitolite

is there a way to create *wild repositories* on-demand without the need of adding the *CREATOR* users public key to *gitolite* first? I'd like to setup a namespace *anon/CREATOR/* where anyone is able to create repositories.

Unfortunately this does not work:

```
repo anon/CREATOR/[a-z0-9]+
    C    = @all
    RW+D = CREATOR
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that:

- `CREATOR` is "parametrise the name of the user creating the repo" (from the [Gitolite page on "wild" repos](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/wild.html))
- The public key is the way to know *who* is doing a git command (like a git clone for creating said wild repo)

I doubt that it is possible to allow `@all` to create a repo based on one's name.